# Sql server compact for windows app using visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, windows, sql-server-2008

I am working on windows app where i need to use sql server compact . I tried various articles for using it in visual studio 2010

[Private Installation for SQL Compact](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33661/Creating-a-Private-Installation-for-SQL-Compact)

[Working with SQL Server Compact in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg606540%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

but didn't get any satisfactory answers .Please suggest me best solution available for this .

Comment: How do you mean "Can't we access sql compact as we do in sql server". Fundamentally SQL CE is very different topologically to SQL Server. CE is an in proc solution, whilst SQL Server is a client-server solution.

Comment: Yeah i am sorry for my above mistake. I am new with sql compact , don't know much about it.

Comment: Nono...don't worry. The point here is to learn...sorry if I sounded hostile. I meant, who did you expect to "connect" to SQL Server CE? Do you mean using SSMS?

Comment: @aron my motive is to insert text data in SQL Server CE table and retrieve for future use . What are the various steps should be taken to perform this task .

Answer (score 1):

If you use the nuget package (http://nuget.org/) you can simply look it up and install it. Otherwise you just copy the sql server compact dll's to your exe directory and include System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

Comment: i want to know we have to include only System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll or sqlceca35.dll,
sqlceca35.dll,
sqlcecompact35.dll,
sqlceer35EN.dll,
sqlceme35.dll,
sqlceoledb35.dll,
sqlceqp35.dll,
sqlcese35.dll also .

Comment: Just the first one. Your program does need the other ones but you don't have to include them, just copy them to your output dir.

Answer (score 0):

There are various different ways to interface with a database. As an OO framework .net has various abstractions for database access. The main ones are (vanilla) ADO.NET (not recommended), EntityFramework, nHibernate and LinqToSQL (not recommended). They will all work with SQL CE very well.

Given what you have described so far I would recommend EntityFramework CodeFirst SQL CE. [Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) has a good blog on an old version of this tech. I would start by just installing the premade nuget for [SQL CE EF](http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact).